# How to delete an object from a dictionary after a certain period of time in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Let's suppose we have a dictionary with some values like this

```
const members = {
"NAME1": "TEST1",
"NAME2": "TEST2",
"NAME3": "TEST3"
};
```

How would we delete a value after a **certain time period**, let's say 5 minutes.
Note that we are using this on an Nodejs/ExpressJS server and it can not block the whole server. It has to be either a thread or something similar.

`delete['NAME1']` and then we call this. 
What is the **right way** to do this? I tried making a loop and sleeping 5 minutes but that doesn't work as it blocks the whole server until it sleep passes away.

Comment: There are no threads in Node.js, and I suspect there never will be -- they have explicitly designed everything around an event loop. Meaning that everything that happens in Node either is an event handler processing an event off the queue, or an event emitter that queues events to be processed next time. Both block the single Node.js thread during their execution. That's all there is to it. Sleeping is just setting a timeout which will cause a task to be processed in due time. You can block by executing a busy loop but that's just waste of Node.js processing time.

Comment: I mustve done something other wrong then, thank you for the input.

Comment: @amn one question what would happend if I created a function (with settimeout) and called that one function 3 times or would it cancel the previous?
Basically delaydelete(name); I call it 3 times would it just execute the this function 3 times if there is a delay or would it only execute the last call?

Comment: What I have described is explained in detail at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/#header-node-js-core-concepts, section "Node.js core concepts".

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself why you want to delay removing something when you can just remove immediately? Are you trying to implement some "vacuuming" of unused or stale cache entries or other kind of data structures? Why don't you describe what is it you actually are designing? But no, `setTimeout` can be called many times and will just cause as many tasks (calls to the function you specify as argument to `setTimeout`) to be scheduled for after specified period of time elapses. The only way to replace a scheduled call you have requested earlier is to call `clearTimeout`.

Comment: @amn that is what I was looking for, does clearTimeout cancel EVERY timeout or just one? There is a reason that I need to delete it after a delay. Rather than implementing a field created_time and then checking if its too old. I want to schedule a delete and to cancel it if update the user updates the field

Comment: Why don't you read  up on it at the place where it is specified: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args, in particular pay attention to the return value for the function.

Comment: @amn thank you for clarifying. I will read but I usually ask questions because I dont understand the documentation very clearly but this answers it.

Comment: I understand. Well, to explain it briefly, you schedule a task with a `setTimeout` call which returns an identifier (a number), which you can at any time use to cancel the task with `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `setTimeout` and the `delete` keyword:

```js
let members = {
  "NAME1": "TEST1",
  "NAME2": "TEST2",
  "NAME3": "TEST3"
};

const ONE_SECOND = 1000;
setTimeout(() => {
  delete members['NAME2'];
  console.log(members);
}, ONE_SECOND * 3);

console.log(members);
```

Comment: Remember this is a nodeJS server, will my other operations be stuck upon coming to seeing the function, setTimeout()?

Comment: `setTimeout` will push a function onto the event queue. It's not blocking.

Comment: Yup just tested, thank you! I will make sure to mark it as the correct answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer. That way other users will see at a glance that the question has been answered.